# Finding Records with Specific dateTime Difference in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have an audit Trail table where I store the records with time taken for each transaction

Ex:
DateTime                          ReferenceID           Status
2012-08-29 18:54:22      abc                       
2012-08-29 18:54:28      abc                               Success
2012-08-29 18:54:32      abcd
2012-08-29 18:54:48      abcd                                Success

I want to find out all the records that took more than say 10 seconds.

My output should look like
ReferenceID        TimeTaken
abcd                          16

Thanks
Soni

Comment: I would think you would need at least two datetime fields for this.  Care to share your full table structure?

Comment: Hi Mike ,The example shows how we store the data. Basically I insert a record at the start of the transaction and insert another record once the transaction is processed. I dont have another datetime field in the table. And unfortunately I cant share the complete table structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a self join on the table from the records with blank Status to the corresponding Success record and calculate the difference between them. This query is assuming you only have the two records for each ReferenceID, if there may be more you will have to do some further filtering.

```
select d1.ReferenceID,
  TimeStampDiff(SECOND, d1.Dttm, d2.Dttm) TimeTaken
from data d1
left join data d2 on d2.ReferenceID = d1.ReferenceID
  and d2.Status = 'Success'
where d1.Status = ''
  and TimeStampDiff(SECOND, d1.Dttm, d2.Dttm) > 10
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2c2e4/1)

Comment: you wrote "self join", but are doing a "left join". This does not seem correct.

Comment: They are not mutually exclusive, "self join" just indicates that you are joining back to the original table. Can be an inner join, left out join, etc.

Comment: I just checked on [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c1c9f/1) (I removed a row of data), and using LEFT JOIN works correctly because your `WHERE` condition excludes rows where d2.Dttm is null.